# How do i add a int parameter to my textBox1 update method?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In form1:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Searcher searcher = new Searcher(this);
}

private delegate void NameCallBack(string varText, int varNumber);

public void UpdateTextBox(string input, int numberofdirsleft)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        textBox1.BeginInvoke(new NameCallBack(UpdateTextBox), new object[] { input });
    }
    else
    {
        textBox1.Text = input;
    }
}
```

In a new class top:

```
static MainWindow myform;

public Searcher(MainWindow form)
{
    myform = form;
}
```

In the new class in a `foreach`:

```
if (m_pars.IncludeSubDirsChecked)
{
    DirectoryInfo[] subDirInfos = dirInfo.GetDirectories();
    int counter = subDirInfos.Length;
    foreach (DirectoryInfo subDirInfo in subDirInfos)
    {
        if (m_stop)
        {
            break;
        }

        // Recursion:
        SearchDirectory(subDirInfo);
        counter = counter - 1;
        myform.UpdateTextBox(subDirInfo.FullName,counter);
    }
}
```

If in `form1` I was removing the `int numberofdirsleft` and the `int varNumber` and using only the string it's working fine.
Also in the new class not using the counter variable. Then it's all working fine I see the text in the `textBox1`.

For example in `textBox1` I see:

c:\
c:\temp
c:\temp1....

But now I wanted to see a counter near the text inside the `textBox1`:

> 26 c:\
>   25 c:\temp
>   24 c:\temp1

But the way I did it now with the int variables I added it's throwing an exception in Program.cs on the line:

```
Application.Run(new MainWindow());
```

Parameter count mismatch

```
System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException was unhandled
      IsTransient=false
      Message=Parameter count mismatch.
      Source=mscorlib
      StackTrace:
           at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
           at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
           at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
           at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
           at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
           at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
           at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
           at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
           at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
           at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
           at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
           at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
           at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
           at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
           at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
           at FileSearcher.Program.Main() in e:\filesearch\FileSearcher\FileSearcher\Program.cs:line 17
           at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
           at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
           at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
           at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
      InnerException:
```

What I see in the `foreach` first the variable counter is 26
Then inside the `foreach` I see using a break point that counter is 1
Then next time in the `foreach` counter is 26

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code for your entire `Main` method?  The stack trace doesn't seem to accurately indicate that the line of code that is a problem in `Program.cs` is the one you quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
public void UpdateTextBox(string input, int numberofdirsleft)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        textBox1.BeginInvoke(new NameCallBack(UpdateTextBox), new object[] { input });
    }
    else
    {
        textBox1.Text = input;
    }
}
```

To:

```
public void UpdateTextBox(string input, int numberofdirsleft)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        textBox1.BeginInvoke(new NameCallBack(UpdateTextBox), new object[] { input, numberofdirsleft });
    }
    else
    {
        textBox1.Text = numberofdirsleft.ToString() + " " + input;
    }
}
```

Note how I'm passing both parameters to the Object Array:

```
new object[] { input, numberofdirsleft }
```

Then making use of both of those values when updating the Textbox value.

You also could simply do:

```
    public void UpdateTextBox(string input, int numberofdirsleft)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
            this.textBox1.Text = numberofdirsleft.ToString() + " " + input;
        });
    }
```